# mysql table: index vs primary

Tags: mysql

i am a newbie and am a bit concerned about the efficiency of mysql table. 
what are the pros and cons of making a field in mysql table as

1. index
2. primary

what is the followed practise in deciding on the attributes of a field in a mysql table?
please share your insights, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one primary key in a table.  It should be a column that uniquely identifies each record in your table.  A primary key is not a requirement; for example, you may have a table to implement a many-to-many relationship and a unique id is not needed for those records.

Indexes should be used whenever you must query a table and specify some criteria to filter records based on a column's value (e.g. WHERE clause).  There is a lot to learn about indexes, for example:  when to create an index on one column vs. multiple columns in the same index.  Read [the documentation on the MySQL website about indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html) to learn more.

Comment: thanks AJ for your answer, i did not intend to ask the definition of primary key or index. what i actually wanted to know was what are the best practises followed while deciding the primary key and/or index. some practical tips from some experienced user. hope you understand now.

Comment: @gamebit07 – I believe my answer provides more than just a definition.  “A primary key is not a requirement…” would be considered advice/best practices, not a definition.  Mentioning single column vs. multi-column indexes is advice/best practices, not a definition.  If you’re looking for a definition that would apply to all situations, it’s going to be VERY high-level and won’t solve your problem.  Reason:  every database will be different.  If you were to provide an example of a database schema, I would be happy to give more specific advice on optimizing indexes for that specific scenario.